# overloading constructors not working

Tags: java, constructor, overloading

For my program I have two rectangle constructors. One with no parameters, and one with 2 parameters for length and width. In my test class I call upon the constructor with the 2 parameters but I get the error `rectangle in class rectangle can not be applied to given types` can anyone tell me why it is only recognizing the default rectangle constructor but not the constructor with the parameters. Thank you

class to find rectangle.

```
public class Rectangle
{
 //declares instance variables
 private int length;
 private int width;


 /**
  * Rectangle
  * sets the length and width to default values
  * pre: none
  * post: length and with set = to 1
  */

 public void Rectangle()
 {    
  // sets length and width as 1 if no parameters are entered
  length = 1;
  width = 1;
}

/**
 * Rectangle
 * sets the length and width to values entered by user
 * pre: none
 * post: length and width set = to user input
 */
public void Rectangle ( int len, int wid)
{
    //sets the legth and width as the user variable

    length = len;
    width = wid;
}
```

test class

```
//rectangle object with default numbers
Rectangle rectan1= new Rectangle();
System.out.println("Area of rectangle with no parameters: "+ 
rectan1.area());

//rectangle object using parameters    
Rectangle rectan2= new Rectangle(2,3);  //ERROR RECEIVED HERE
System.out.println("Perimeter of rectangle with parameters: "+ 
rectan2.perimeter());
```

Comment: Remove `void`, otherwise it's a method and not a constructor (your other constructor is not working either - any class with no constructor can be constructor with `new ClassName()`).

Comment: @Dukeling This worked. Thank you

Comment: @Dukeling has it right. You are actually calling the default constructor for the class since you have not defined any. Removing void will turn them into constructors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the void keyword from the constructor:

```
 public Rectangle()
 {    
  this(1,1); // execute second constructor;
}

public void Rectangle ( int len, int wid)
{
    //sets the legth and width as the user variable

    length = len;
    width = wid;
}
```

Please look at this [oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html). As you can see constructors do not return anything, but methods do.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `void` if you're creating a method, if you want to create a constructor just remove it, like so:

```
public Rectangle()
 {   
...
}
```

and

```
public Rectangle ( int len, int wid)
 {   
...
}
```

happy coding